# Which ability modifiers apply to which Defenses?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, defense

I'm creating a level 1 character. When I got to the 'filling out the character sheet' part I really didn't understand what modifiers there were for Defenses or how they were applied. I am new to D&D and just needed a little help with this!

Comment: What books do you have? This is explained fairly well in the various "how to build your character" sections.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I did follow both of those guides to fill out my Character Sheet, but still had a lot of doubts! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the PHB1
In Page 17, Player's Handbook Explains the abilities that modifies the Defenses!

"For Fortitude defense, you add the higher of your Strength or Constitution ability modifiers.

For Reflex defense, you add the higher of your Dexterity or Intelligence ability modifiers.

For Will defense, you add the higher of your Wisdom or Charisma ability modifiers.

If you wear light armor or no armor, you also add the higher of your Dexterity or Intelligence ability modifiers to your Armor Class."

:) Much back and forth through the book and finally found it!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a link to a step by step approach to [filling out character sheets](http://dungeoneeringnewbie.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/filling-out-dd-4e-character-sheets-a-step-by-step-approach/).

In the above, they discuss defenses:

> Armor Class = 10 + Armor Value + Shield Bonus ( if wearing Light Armor either +Dex or +Int modifier, whichever is highest) + ½ character level (formula from here)
>
> For Bob: 10 + 2 (Armor Value) + 3 (Shield Bonus, Light Armor: higher of INT or DEX modifier) + o (1/2 LVL) = 15 AC

...

You'll note that in the image:

[image]

There are little grey directional things? That means that those two stats are linked to that defense. Put the highest of your str or con in your fort bonus, your dex or int in your ref bonus, and your wis or cha in your will bonus.

If you need another guide, I also recommend [this one](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-4Th-Edition-Dungeons-and-Dragons-Character).

I also urge you to buy the essentials books (Heroes of the Fallen Lands, Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms), as they are far better written and detail this entire process very well.

Comment: Additionally most classes that use something other than DEX or INT as a primary stat and don't wear heavy armor get class features to make up for the lack of AC. These are typically either flat bonus to armor or the use of a stat other than DEX/INT to apply to AC.